# Google Chrome: How to open the tab context menu with keyboard shortcut(s) only (i.e., *without* mouse) and *without* any extensions

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I can't use extensions as my Chrome is ["managed by my organisation"](https://www.howtogeek.com/410106/why-does-chrome-say-its-managed-by-your-organization/). One thing I discovered now is that [tab grouping](https://www.howtogeek.com/656707/how-to-enable-and-use-tab-groups-in-google-chrome/) is possible, even with the above constraint. That's great news and quite a relief but ideally I'd like to use the tab grouping feature without touching my mouse. [This Q&A is about the same thing](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/f1uwqv/right_click_context_menu_for_current_tab_via/) but so far is only a stub and doesn't yet provide a solution. Hence asking here on StackExchange.

In short: **It's the mouse's "right click" on the tab which I'm trying to avoid.** --- Keyboard "accelerators" can do the rest...

Answer (score 0):

`Shift + F6 + (release F6 while still holding Shift) F10`